# Why is imread returning NULL?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to import an images dataset to **test_image** variable. I'd like to try this way because in my opinion it looks better. But I am getting this error:

> (build-in function imread() returned NULL

```
import cv2 as cv
import os

test_images_path = './test_images/'

test_image = [cv.imread(os.path.join(test_images_path, image) for image in  os.listdir(test_images_path))]
```

Comment: now I am getting new error that there's must be returned INT value not str

Comment: Check my answer and up vote it if its helpful. If it solved your problem, consider clicking on the checkbox near it to select it as the official problem solver.

Answer (score 0):

Closing parenthesis of `cv.imread()` was at the wrong place:

```
import cv2 as cv
import os

test_images_path = './test_images/'

test_images = [cv2.imread(os.path.join(test_images_path, image)) for image in os.listdir(test_images_path)]

for img in test_images:
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think u have not clearly specified the path from where u are trying to fetch image is plz make sure u saved the image in same location where ur python file is saved

Comment: test_images_path = './test_images'
print(os.listdir(test_images_path))

Comment: and there's displaying an images list